# How to read a file (exe) like bin text application in Malware Analysis by Python

Tags: python, analysis, malware, antivirus

**How to read a file (exe)** like  bin text application in Malware Analysis but by Python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At Stack Overflow we work on the policy that the user should show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Comment: Can you also clarify the question besides what did you try? What would be an ideal outcome of your task?